# for loop decrementing by 2 to 0 and summing up the values that were generated before getting to 0

Tags: java, math

I am trying to find a way to count down from the int that is input by a user and then add each second value as i count down to 0

for example.

{user inputs 10

program counts down 8,6,4,2,0

then add 10 + 8 + 6 + 4 +2 +0= 30

}

how can I do this using a nested for loop

so far I have only been able to take user input, and count down by 2 each time. I get to 0 but have no way of adding every second value.
My code:

so far, it just counts to 0

public class Week5b {
static Scanner userVal = new Scanner (System.in);

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  //printTable();
    reverseAddSkip();
public static void reverseAddSkip(){      

         System.out.println("Please enter an integer"); 


         for (int i = userVal.nextInt(); i >=0; i-=2){


         System.out.println(i) ;
        }/* this creates a loop where the variable i is equal to user input; 
            the condition for the loop to continue is whether the input is larger or   equal to 0; the update part of the loop takes 2 away each time, as if it were -- (which takes away one each time) */

}
```

}
How would I write that out mathematically?
Adding the sum of i-=2 to the original value of i.
You type 11 , it counts 9 7 5 3 1 , then adds 11 9 7 5 3 1. and give you the sum.

don't know how to sum every 2 numbers decrementing by 2, from a user value.

You input put  50, it counts down by 2 to 0
you put 51 it counts down by 2 to 0 
but I haven't found away to sum all then numbers that were generated before getting to 0
:/

Comment: How do you declare an int variable in Java? How do you add two numbers in Java?

Answer (score 0):

NoGlitching,

You need to look at the **control flow** of your program - which is to say, the path it takes upon execution.

You should also look at **using more variables**.

I'll give you the pseudocode I would use, because I think it's important for you to be able to write the code yourself:

- Make a new integer called OriginalInput.
- Make a new integer called RunningTotal.
- Set RunningTotal to 0.
- Store the user's input in OriginalInput.
- Loop through OriginalInput.

  - Print the current OriginalInput.
  - Add the current OriginalInput to RunningTotal.
- When the loop is finished:

  - Print RunningTotal.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Appreciate your help bro, but I am stumped because I have to do it using nested for loops. Basically, I think there is a mathematical solution. i-=2 is eventually 0. so even i-=2+i    8-=2+8=14? that would be adding 6 and is which are the first 2 numbers counting down by 2 but I can't express how do it on paper :(

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

```
        // First you equalize j with i

         input =  userVal.nextInt();
         j = i; // Put the user input in j first. for instance 11.

     for (int i = input; i >=0; i-=2)
         {
           if (i >= 0) // If i is not below 0
              {
                j += i; // Add to j what i has now (everytime -2)
                // put a system out print here to show what was added
                // J starts as 11 and adds 9,7,5,3,1 then nothing. So it ends as 36.
              }


          }
     // outside the For loop after it ends but INSIDE your method, you get the sum from the variable j!
```

Comment: Tried, but seems just count down from the number I input to 0, I want to add all of the numbers I have to count in order to reach 0, so if someone inputs 12, program should output 42

Comment: Here is the solution on my same comment edited. Hope it helps. Accept it if case solved. Otherwise please leave a reply.

Comment: Nah, it makes sense, but doesn't work. Thing is, I just need to find way of either remembering the number line, or storing each value as it counts down in the loop into a variable. I just don't know  how to do it. So like imagine, i-=2....so every time 2 is taken away, that value is then stored in a variable, obviously, the first time it doesn't decrement or increment so the initial value will also be stored in that same variable giving the right result, and still ticking the box that it counts down by 2 to 0 before printing the answer